# issue with cycle plugin ie8

Tags: jquery, css, plugins, cycle

i am currently building this site for a university project

http://cutecupcak.es/

i am having issues with the 'testimonial' section on the home page

the section uses the cycle plugin to flip through the quotes..

problem is in ie8 as the blockquote has a white background which i can not get rid off...
strangley it works in all other browsers far as i can see from testing!

get rid of teh cycle plugin and it works - however same problem occurs even if i use a p tag rather than blockquote..

any ideas !!

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the following code snippet inside your cycle plugin call:

```
cleartypeNoBg: true,
```